# Get default dateformat of webserver

Tags: c#, date-format

I want to know the default dateformat of webserver where my code is situated. I want to know whether it is mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy or else. Is there any property for it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat